# How to Split at word not at a char in c#

Tags: c#, split

How do I split a string at word not at a char, Like 
I want to split this string into an array of strings:

```
Hello /*End*/ World /*End*/ Bye /*End*/ live /*End*/
```

I want to split at `/*End*/`
so the array will be like this

```
{Hello,World,Bye,live}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an overload `Split` function that takes an array of strings and you can give only 1 string, like below.

```
string input = "Hello /End/ World /End/ Bye /End/ live /End/ ";
var output = input.Split(new[] { "/*End*/" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`string.Split(string[], StringSplitOptions)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) overload.

```
var parts = str.Split(new[] {@"/*End*/"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the regex class for this: (From `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace)

```
string[] Result = Regex.Split(Input, "end");
```

It gives you a string array that is splitted by the pattern you specified.

Comment: Do I have to import any thing to use this ?

Comment: No, this comes with the .NET framework. Just add "using System.Text.RegularExpressions;" at the top of your source code file.

Comment: You can do quite a lot with regular expressions, you could start here:[Wikipedia RegEx article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and find a lot of regex-syntax at this [CheatSheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/)

Answer (score 1):

```
        var str = @"Hello /End/ World /End/ Bye /End/ live /End/ ";

        var words = str.Split(new string[] { "/End/" }, System.StringSplitOptions.None);

        foreach(var word in words)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(word);    
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try Regex

```
  string input = "Hello /*End*/ World /*End*/ Bye /*End*/ live /*End*/";
  string pattern = "/*End*/";            // Split on hyphens 

  string[] substrings = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple regex pattern:

```
\/\*End\*\/
```

[see demo](http://www.systemtextregularexpressions.com/regex.split?p=XC9cKkVuZFwqXC8%3D&t=SGVsbG8gLypFbmQqLyBXb3JsZCAvKkVuZCovIEJ5ZSAvKkVuZCovIGxpdmU%3D)